# How to convert nvarchar into int type for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to count the total the column [Trans Det Amt ex Tax] like the following:

```
SELECT 
    Loyalty_Type_Code, 
    COUNT([Loyalty_Number]), 
    FORMAT(SUM([Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax]), '##,###,###,##0')
FROM 
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
WHERE 
    Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY 
    Loyalty_Type_Code
UNION
SELECT 
    'TOTAL', 
    COUNT(*) AS CCC, 
    COUNT(*) AS BBB
FROM 
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '67,527,726,031' to data type int.

So I tried to convert this to INT type by using the following:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax)
FROM 
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
```

But the result still said

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '67,527,726,031' to data type int

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: seems like the string you are converting has commas in it. remove them first and convert

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the value to a string:

```
SELECT Loyalty_Type_Code , COUNT([Loyalty_Number]),  
       SUM([Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax]))
FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
WHERE Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY Loyalty_Type_Code
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL', COUNT(*) AS CCC, COUNT(*) AS BBB
FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL;
```

All the types in a `UNION ALL` need to be the same.  If it sees a string and an integer -- as in the third column -- it will try to convert the string to an integer.  That is not possible with commas.

Alternatively, you can convert both columns to strings.  A simpler method uses `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Loyalty_Type_Code, 'Total'), 
       COUNT([Loyalty_Number]),  
       FORMAT(SUM([Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax]), '##,###,###,##0')
FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
WHERE Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( Loyalty_Type_Code, () );
```

Answer (score 0):

`select CONVERT(bigint, Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax)`

`int` cant hold number that big

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the value to a string, try removing the commas and using a data type cast that is large enough to store that data:

```sql
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('67,527,726,031',',','') AS BIGINT);
```

This will strip the commas and store the data as a `BIGINT`.

I'm not 100% sure, but you may need to `CAST` the `SUM` as a larger data type if you're going to be adding up a lot of values.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4beb372a5f84f1584e0bc50e2907ae72)